# Becks USA AB InBev

Tags: brewing, breweries, german-beers

Can anyone tell me if the USA market Becks adheres to the current definition of the Reinheitsgebot (aka German Purity Law) and what grains are used?

I ask because I swear it tastes "ricey" like all the other American InBev beers, like Miller etc but friends swear "Oh no, it's made to German spec" and I note it's made in St. Louis where the devil makes gross Anheuser Busch products.

Thanks in advance!

- Sincerely, 
  Someone Get Me a Growler of Dirt Wolf

Answer (score 3):

AB claims it is. In reference to it being brewed in the US,

> Chris Cools, the head of the German branch of the company, says he's confident that Becks will lose none of its German character. He believes the beer's taste will be enough to ensure success. Becks is brewed according to Germany's Beer Purity Law, the Reinheitsgebot, that dates back hundreds of years and is made in exactly the same way in 15 countries.

The classic, strict interpretation of the law would require only barley to be used as a grain. There are more lax standards currently, revised as the [Provisional German Beer Law](http://archiv.jura.uni-saarland.de/BGBl/TEIL1/1993/19931400.1.HTML) (in German), but by using the name of Reinheitsgebot, it's safe to assume they are intending to convey the original restrictions.

Sources:

- [Beverage Daily](http://www.beveragedaily.com/Manufacturers/US-Beck-s-ain-t-brewed-in-Germany!-Angry-man-sues-AB-InBev-for-millions)
- [GACCSouth](http://www.gaccsouth.com/en/news/single-view/artikel/german-brewer-becks-tries-to-crack-the-american-market-1/?cHash=949f72dfbb559f95789e3a5a2c633d29)
- [Beer Truth](http://www.beertruth.com/beer-review/becks/)

Comment: Thank you for replying!  For $1 a pint it's hard to not like Beck's, but I swear there is a taste in it that reminds me of the new Miller High Life, PBR, etc... a taste I attribute to inferior/cheaper grains like rice or millet.  I could be completely wrong, I'm just an amateur beer brewer and pro drinker... but i admit freely that strong hops have wrecked my palate for mild beers.

Thanks again!